# Rails 6 has_one relation explicit class_name not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently upgrading an app from rails 5.2 to 6.0.2. Using ruby 2.6.3
One of the issues I'm seeing is around the inferred class for a relation
I have two models

```rb
class Site::Page::Metadata < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :page, class_name: "Site::BlockPage"
end
```

and

```rb
class Site::BlockPage < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :metadata, dependent: :destroy, class_name: "Site::Page::Metadata", foreign_key: "page_id"
end
```

Since upgrading to rails 6 with the setup as above I get uninitialized constant error when trying to access a pages metadata.
`ActionView::Template::Error: uninitialized constant Site::BlockPage::Site::Page::Metadata`
Where it doesn't look to be correctly inferring the class of the relation.
However when I reflect on the association it looks correct

```
irb(main):001:0> Site::BlockPage.reflect_on_association(:metadata)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Reflection::HasOneReflection:0x00007fbeffea7020 @name=:metadata, @scope=nil, @options={:dependent=>:destroy, :class_name=>"Site::Page::Metadata", :foreign_key=>"page_id", :autosave=>true}, @active_record=Site::BlockPage (call 'Site::BlockPage.connection' to establish a connection), @klass=nil, @plural_name="metadata", @type=nil, @foreign_type=nil, @constructable=true, @association_scope_cache=#<Concurrent::Map:0x00007fbeffea6ee0 entries=0 default_proc=nil>>
```

I then tried updating the relation on the `Site::BlockPage` to be

```
has_one :metadata, dependent: :destroy, class_name: "::Site::Page::Metadata", foreign_key: "page_id"
```

With the root namespace prefix and it now references the `ActiveStorageValidations::Metadata` class from the [active_storage_validations](https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/active_storage_validations) gem.

I'm assuming this is something incorrect in my autoloading setup but I'm a bit stuck on where to start digging.

Comment: How are these files organized? `app/models/site/block_page.rb` and `app/models/site/page/metadata.rb`? Are you using the new Zeitwerk autoloader?

Comment: I would always recommend nesting your namespaces rather than chaining them e.g. `module Site; module Page; class Metadata;end;end;end` rather than `Site::Page::Metadata`. These 2 styles directly impact the way ruby constant lookup works. https://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely a result of changing to the new Zeitwerk autoloader. It has revealed a bug in your code that the old Rails autoloader was papering over.

```
class Site::BlockPage
  has_one :metadata, dependent: :destroy, class_name: "Site::Page::Metadata", foreign_key: "page_id"
end
```

Here `Site::Page::Metadata` is ambiguous. It could mean `Site::BlockPage::Site::Page::Metadata` or `Site::Page::Metadata`.

If `Site::Page::Metadata` is already loaded, you're good.

If it isn't, the Rails autoloader takes over.

Prior to Zeitwerk this worked because of how the Rails autoloader worked. It would catch the exception when a constant was missing and then look around for a file path which matched. In this case it would try `Site::BlockPage::Site::Page::Metadata`, get an exception, and look for `site/block_page/site/page/metadata.rb`. This doesn't exist. That doesn't exist, so it tries `Site::Page::Metadata` and looks for `site/page/metadata.rb`. That exists and that's what gets loaded.

Zeitwerk does the opposite. When Rails starts up it scans your directories, infers the class name from the filename, and [registers it to be autoloaded](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-autoload) from that file. For example, if it finds `app/models/site/page/metadata.rb` it runs `Site::Page.autoload(:Metadata, app/models/site/page/metadata.rb)` registering references to `Site::Page::Metadata` to load `app/models/site/page/metadata.rb`. The `Site::Page::Metadata` constant exists, but its content hasn't yet been loaded.

When Rails 6 looks for `Site::BlockPage::Site::Page::Metadata` it gets an exception and that's it. Zeitwerk does not catch the exception and continue searching like the old autoloader did.

Because Zeitwerk creates constants for every class at startup it is much more reliable. It does not rely on the order classes are loaded. But it does not match the quirks of the old Rails autoloader.

For this reason, and others, it's preferable to spell out nested classes and modules. And it's very important that the file path matches Rails's expectations.

```
# app/models/site/block_page.rb
module Site
  class BlockPage < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :metadata, dependent: :destroy, class_name: "Site::Page::Metadata", foreign_key: "page_id"
  end
end

# app/models/site/page/metadata.rb
module Site
  class Page
    class Metadata < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :page, class_name: "Site::BlockPage"
    end
  end
end
```

You can see how Zeitwerk is loading your classes with `Rails.autoloaders.main` or by throwing `Rails.autoloaders.log!` into your `config/application.rb`. See [Autloading and Reloading Constants (Zeitwerk Mode) - Troubleshooting](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#troubleshooting).

tl;dr

- [Used nested namespaces. Avoid chaining](https://rubystyle.guide/#namespace-definition).
- Make ambiguous classes unambiguous with a leading `::`.
- Follow the Rails file path naming conventions.

See [Understanding Zeitwerk in Rails 6](https://medium.com/cedarcode/understanding-zeitwerk-in-rails-6-f168a9f09a1f) by Marcelo Casiraghi.

Comment: Excellent answer. Hopefully one day rails will have better generators that don't propagate the anti-pattern of using the scope operator.

Comment: Thanks for the super detailed answer!
I've tried disabling the new loader just to confirm it is the root of the issue by [opting out](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#opting-out) but I still face the same issues.
The issue I have with the nested namespaces at this point is that our application already has a site class at `app/models/site.rb` which is quite core so if I did move to the nested namespace we'd have a module naming conflict for the Site module. I'm not sure the best way to get around such a conflict

Comment: Interestingly I just went to confirm what loader we were using without the opt outw with `Rails.application.config.autoloader` and it turns out I hadn't actually yet enabled zeitwerk. With Zeitwerk enabled the classes load correctly as before without any changes made to them...

Comment: @KyleByrne `Site` doesn't have to be a `module`. If `Site` is already a class then continue to use it as a class. `class Site class BlockPage ... end end`